# How can I force Chrome to display the actual page's URL instead of the search query in the Chrome address bar when performing searches on Google?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I have noticed today that Google has started displaying the search query in the Chrome address bar rather than the actual page's URL when performing searches on Google.

How can I force Google Chrome to display the actual page's URL instead of the search query in the Chrome address bar when performing searches on Google?

Example:

[image]

I use Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the  [Suspicious Site Reporter extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/suspicious-site-reporter/jknemblkbdhdcpllfgbfekkdciegfboi) from Google forces the browser to show the full URL

Or

You can edit chrome flags (works till v78)

chrome://flags >

- Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Scheme > Disabled
- Omnibox UI Hide Steady-State URL Trivial Subdomains > Disabled

Or

From : [Google Chrome for Windows address bar fix (startup parameter)](https://amp.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/e9e3er/ver79_chrome_wont_display_https_or_http_and/)

> Step 1: Find Google Chrome desktop icon.
>
> Step 2: Right-click on Google Chrome icon and select Properties.
>
> Step 3: Look for the "Target:" field, place the curser after the file
>   path, and after the quotes with a space between.
>
> Step 4: Copy and paste
>   "--disable-features=OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlScheme,OmniboxUIExperimentHideSteadyStateUrlTrivialSubdomains"
>   in the field.
>
> Step 5: Press Apply then OK and now you will see full address.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see this flag. what's your version of Google Chrome? Mine is Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) (it got updated a few hours ago). I also tried to go straight to chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-hide-steady-state-url-scheme-and-subdomains but no flag there either.

Comment: Mine is  Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (same as yours). And yes those flags are gone(answer edited).You can use Suspicious Site Reporter extension to do the trick !!!